# Migrateした後にModelを作成するには？

Tags: laravel

Laravel でDB定義を以下のコマンドで実行しました。

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

この後に自動でModelファイル/クラスを作る方法ありますか？

Modelを作るのと同時にmigrationを作る方法というのは見かけたのですが、
**Migrateした後に**、Modelを作る方法はないのかと気になりました。

Laravelは6.x系を使っています。

Comment: これはMigration元にModelファイルを作る方法ということですか？`$ php artisan make:model ModelName`で作れますよ。何の目的かを教えればいい答えを教えると思います。

Answer (score -1):

下記のコマンドでマイグレーションファイルの作成とモデルクラスファイルの作成を同時に行うことが出来ます。

`$ php artisan make:model Flight --migration`

もしくは、

`$ php artisan make:model Flight -m`

https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/eloquent.html

Comment: 質問に「Modelを作るのと同時にmigrationを作る方法というのを見かけた」と書いてあるので、おそらく質問者さんは知っていると思われます。同時ではなくて別々で作りたいという要望のようです